# How do I change a link using a tag of django template engine?

Tags: python, django

Sorry I don't know English well.
I'm working on a following system.
But I don't know how to turn the link from follow to no longer follow.

Link (template.html)

```
{% if request.user == user.following %}
       <a href="{% url 'remove-follower' pk=user.pk id=request.user.pk %}">no longer follow</a>
{% endif %}
{% if request.user == user.following %}
       <a href="{% url 'add-follower' pk=user.pk id=request.user.pk %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Follower(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='following')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='followers')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('follower', 'following')

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s follow %s' % (self.follower, self.following)
```

views.py

```
def AddFollowerView(request, pk, id):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        userFollow = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        Follower.objects.create(follower=user, following=userFollow)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def RemoveFollowerView(request, pk, id):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
        userFollow = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        Follower.objects.filter(follower=user, following=userFollow).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

urls.py

```
path('follow/<int:pk>/<int:id>/', AddFollowerView, name="add-follower"),
    path('no-longer-follow/<int:pk>/<int:id>/', RemoveFollowerView, name="remove-follower"),
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```html
{% if request.user == user.following %}
  <a href="{% url 'remove-follower' pk=user.pk id=request.user.pk %}">no longer follow</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'add-follower' pk=user.pk id=request.user.pk %}">Follow</a>
{% endif %}
```

So if the user is following another user, the user will have the option to remove the follower. Otherwise, the user can choose to follow the user.

Comment: Why is `pk=user.pk id=request.user.pk` though? Shouldn't both of them be the same or is there some sort of misunderstanding in between. If that 's the case, try changing the pk to `pk=request.user.pk` or the other way around

Comment: Yes, something has improved, but it hasn't solved the link problem.

Comment: Can you please describe the current problem in more details?

Comment: The view, and the model work correctly, but the link with which one follows a person does not change and remains follow.

Comment: So, there is a solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of one